# Raising and moving pawns in easy chess game

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a simple chess game (I am learning javascript). I'v made everything except moving pawns.
Can someone explain me how to do that ? I just want to move them from 1 square to antoher wihout any principles of game.

```
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

        const checkers = document.querySelectorAll('.board');
        const squares = document.querySelectorAll('#checker1 td');

        for (const checker of checkers) {
            checker.addEventListener("click", function(){
                const tableVisibility = this.firstElementChild.style.visibility;
                if (tableVisibility != 'visible') {
                this.firstElementChild.style.visibility = (tableVisibility == '')?'hidden':'';
                }
            }, false);

        }

        for (const square of squares) {
            square.addEventListener("click", function() {

                const styleComputed = getComputedStyle(this);
                const calaPlansza = this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;

                if {(popedPiece == null) && (styleComputed.cursor == 'pointer')) {
                    this.style.setProperty('visibility', )
                }
                if {(popedPiece != null) && (styleComputed.cursor != 'pointer')) {
                    this.style.setProperty('opacity', "")
                    this.classList.add(popedPiece.className);
                    popedPiece = null;
                    calaPlansza.dataset.moves = (calaPlansza.dataset.moves == '');
                }
            }, false);

        }
    }, false);

    /**/

    var Clicked = false;
</script>
```

Comment: “Move” as in set new position on the board as “A-3” within your data storage, or “move” as in show the figure moving from start to finish position in an animation on the screen? _“Can someone explain me how to do that ?”_ - please go read [ask]. This is not a tutorial site, you should do your basic research on how to accomplish what you want on your own. We can discuss specific problems with code you have written here, but this is rather a bit too broad to begin with.

Comment: Ok I'v made some changes in my question

Comment: Some more context in code terms would help too. How much code are you not showing here?  What have you tried and what doesn't work?